# Thin client server? Free alternative to 2X?

Tags: thin-client

I've used 2X Thin Client Server for years, but now they have ended their opensource solution, so i wonder if anyone has found a good alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have started working on switching from our 2X Thin Client Servers to [LTSP](http://www.ltsp.org/).  It does take more work to get setup right, but you have a lot more flexibility.

Comment: LTSP installation on Ubuntu is dead easy - stick two network cards in a server, choose the "Install an LTSP server" option from the alternate install CD, done.

Comment: @David, I agree ltps is easy under Ubuntu, but doing some of the things 2X allows you to do within LTSP is a bit tricky.